# Android Camera Rotation Generic

Tags: android, camera, rotation, orientation

Im trying to rotate my camera when the device rotates, iv tried several methods, but none of them seem to work on all devices.

//This Works on my nexus 5 but not on my Samsung galaxy tab

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
{
    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null)
    {
      return;
    }

    try
    {
        mCamera.stopPreview();

        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.set("orientation", "landscape");
        int rotation = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

        int orientation = getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
            } else {
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            }
        }
        else if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90) {
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(270);
            }
        }
        else if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) {
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
            }
        }
        else if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            }
        }

        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

// and i tried this, which is part of the documentation and it doesnt work on my nexus 5:

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
         int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
             new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
             .getRotation();
     int degrees = 0;
     switch (rotation) {
         case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
     }
          int result;
     if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
         result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
     } else {  // back-facing
         result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
     }
     camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
 }
```

Does someone have a working solution for all devices?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it does not work"? You output images are rotated?

Comment: The camera is rotated incorrectly. Sorry if i was not clear in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm not exactly sure what's your issue from the code you provided, here are few things one has to got right when using Camera API and image rotation on Android (the old one - on API <21)

**1. You have to take in account the [orientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html#orientation) of the image sensor.**

The orientation of the sensor means its angle to the device native use-mode. (that's what actually does the google snippet you are using) For phones this is usually being set to portrait, on tablets to landscape.
Here is an excerpt from the documentation, it can make pain in head for a while, but that's just how things work.

> For example, suppose a device has a naturally tall screen. The back-facing camera sensor is mounted in landscape. You are looking at the screen. If the top side of the camera sensor is aligned with the right edge of the screen in natural orientation, the value should be 90. If the top side of a front-facing camera sensor is aligned with the right of the screen, the value should be 270.

**2. Frontfacing camera preview is being mirrored**

If you use frontfacing camera, you have to take in account the implicit mirroring.

**3. These rules are only meant for rotating the Camera preview**

This is important. All this is only meant to allow you to display correctly rotated preview frames on the device screen. Once you take an actual picture, you have to rotate it once again to suit your needs. For front-facing images this might mean mirroring it yourself,...You can see the result of this "weirdness" among all apps on Android. Just take picture in hangouts and share it right away. On various phones you gotta get somewhat weirdly rotated image as the result.

**4. OEMs does not adhere to specs all the time**

All I can say, is that probably no solution will be hasslefree, we got some issues with some particular devices. (as usual on Android:)

**5. Use the CWAC Camera library**

We found [this library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) to be a superior wrapper around the official Camera APIs. Solving practically all of the issues I did mention.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for all the insight, i can see why they made a new camera API. I wont be using the library but it is a useful reference.

Comment: ..back to your issue..you have issue with the preview, or the resulting image? as you can see these are two different things.

Comment: My problem is with the preview, im not actually going to take a photo. I just need the preview